# Trigger on Lead - Variable does not exist: isConverted

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion

Trying to write a trigger that runs on lead conversion after update, I get the error above on trigger.oldMap.

What am I missing?

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

    Boolean isLeadConversionMethod = false;

    public override void afterUpdate() {
        if (!isLeadConversionMethod) {
            LeadConversionMethod();
            isLeadConversionMethod = true;
        }
    }

    public void LeadConversionMethod(){
        Map<Id,Id> leadIdswithOppIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for (Lead l : (List<Lead>)Trigger.New) {
            If (trigger.isUpdate && l.IsConverted && trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).isConverted == false){
                leadIdswithOppIds.put(l.Id,l.convertedopportunityid);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is 'IsConverted' a custom field/standard field? Can you check the api name for this field? check with 'IsConverted__c'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this issue because the compiler does not know the context where it will be used and what it will contain i.e. it does not know the concrete class that will be used. In that case, it will consider `Trigger.oldMap` as `Map<Id,sObject>` (Same is the case with other data context variables i.e. it will consider everything as `sObject`, **you did this typecasting in the `for loop`, similarly you need to do it for other data context variables as well wherever it is used**).

As it considers it as `sObject`, you won't be able to use the **dot notation**. In such cases, you can use following approaches

- Pass the context variables in constructor either via your handler class or via methods i.e. you will have to change your signature of interface to have parameterized methods and assign it to a concrete variable.
- Assign the context variables to a local concrete copy or typecast it to a concrete class in method i.e. Assign `Trigger.oldMap` to `Map<Id, Lead>` and use this variable for your logic.
- Instead of using dot notation, get the field value dynamically using `get` method of `sObject` i.e. instead of using `oldMap.get(l.Id).isConverted`, you can use `oldMap.get(l.Id).get('isConverted')`

Assigning to a concrete local copy or by typecasting

```
public void LeadConversionMethod(){
    Map<Id,Id> leadIdswithOppIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,Lead> leadIdswithLeads = new Map<Id,Lead>();
    leadIdswithLeads = Trigger.OldMap;
    for (Lead l : (List<Lead>)Trigger.New) {
        If (trigger.isUpdate && l.IsConverted && leadIdswithLeads.get(l.Id).isConverted == false){
            leadIdswithOppIds.put(l.Id,l.convertedopportunityid);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `get` method of the `sObject` class

```
public void LeadConversionMethod(){
    Map<Id,Id> leadIdswithOppIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for (Lead l : (List<Lead>)Trigger.New) {
        If (trigger.isUpdate && l.IsConverted && Boolean.valueOf(Trigger.OldMap.get(l.Id).get('isConverted')) == false){
            leadIdswithOppIds.put(l.Id,l.convertedopportunityid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler gets confused here as you are not writing this in the trigger itself. So pass through the old map from a trigger in your function.

Or maybe you can create a class member for it.

rewrite your code as below

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

    Boolean isLeadConversionMethod = false;
    Map<Id, Lead> oldMap = new Map<Id, Lead>();

    public LeadTriggerHandler(Map<Id, Lead> oldMap){
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }
    public override void afterUpdate() {
        if (!isLeadConversionMethod) {
            LeadConversionMethod();
            isLeadConversionMethod = true;
        }
    }

    public void LeadConversionMethod(){
        Map<Id,Id> leadIdswithOppIds = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for (Lead l : (List<Lead>)Trigger.New) {
            If (trigger.isUpdate && l.IsConverted && oldMap.get(l.Id).isConverted == false){
                leadIdswithOppIds.put(l.Id,l.convertedopportunityid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```